# Use UFW (firewall) to deny incoming ping (ICMP) requests?

Tags: networking, security, firewall, ufw

The `ufw` (uncomplicated firewall) command line app does not have any option for disabling incoming ICMP Internet protocol requests. ICMP is used mainly by `ping` to discover IP addresses of servers on the internet or LAN. For security, I'd like to hide my server from ping requests. How should I do that on Ubuntu (preferably using the built-in firewall)?

Answer (score -1):

These `sed` commands will block all ICMP requests (including `ping`):

```bash
sudo sed -i -E 's/^\s*-A\ ufw-before-input\ -p\ icmp\ --icmp-type.*ACCEPT\s*/#\ \0/g' /etc/ufw/before.rules
sudo sed -i -E 's/^\s*-A\ ufw-before-forward\ -p\ icmp\ --icmp-type.*ACCEPT\s*/#\ \0/g' /etc/ufw/before.rules
```

##### Explanation

By default, `ufw` blocks all ICMP requests *except* `ping`s. So you need to disable these ping exceptions (`ACCEPT`s) in `/etc/ufw/before.rules`:

```bash
# ok icmp codes for INPUT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type destination-unreachable -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type time-exceeded -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type parameter-problem -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT

# ok icmp code for FORWARD
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp --icmp-type destination-unreachable -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp --icmp-type time-exceeded -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp --icmp-type parameter-problem -j AfCCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
```